# recover data from unbootable phone with broken touch

Tags: adb, twrp, fastboot, data-recovery

My Oneplus3 touch screen stopped working yesterday. I did some googling and was told that erasing cache through fastboot could be a solution so I did using.

```
fastboot erase cache
```

Now my phone just hangs on the boot screen when trying to boot into android...

I can still get into TWRP and connect through adb I would like to create a backup with:

```
adb backup --twrp
```

but I'm just greeted with the message

```
Now unlock your device and confirm the backup operation...
```

which of course isn't possible without using the touch screen.

Any ideas on how I could recover data?

Edit: I feel like I could get a long way by repairing the cache partition, which would enable me to boot to android and use a USB-OTG mouse or something. Not sure how to do it though.

Answer (score 0):

TWRP adb backup is started immediately, no confirmation needed. You can ignore that message and check `backup.ab` file is growing

```
fastboot erase cache
```

will erase the file system from partition. what you want is

```
fastboot format:ext4 cache
```

that will allow you to boot to android and use a USB-OTG mouse